# What is the "resonance" in nonlinear discrete systems?

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, diffeomorphism

Suppose that you have $2D$ discrete dynamical systesm
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
{\displaystyle x_{t + 1}} & {\displaystyle =} & {\displaystyle\operatorname{f}\left(x_{t},y_{t}\right)}
\\
{\displaystyle y_{t + 1}} & {\displaystyle =} & {\displaystyle\operatorname{g}\left(x_t,y_t\right)}
\end{array}\right.
$$
and $\operatorname{f}, \operatorname{g}$ are non-linear function.

At a fixed point $\left(x^{*}, y^{*}\right)$, its linearized system is defined as follows.
\begin{align} 
  \left(x_{t + 1} - x^{*}\right) =
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
      \frac{\partial\operatorname{f}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\operatorname{f}}{\partial y}
\\
      \frac{\partial\operatorname{g}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\operatorname{g}}{\partial y}\\
    \end{array}
  \right]\left(x_{t} - x^{*}\right)
\end{align}
A fixed point is called **center** if the Jacobian matrix at a fixed point have the complex conjugate eigenvalues, and a center fixed point is called **resonant** if the eigenvalues are roots of unity.

I know at a resonant center fixed point, the linearized system have periodic orbits near the origin, but what is the result of being resonant on the former non-linear system ( I can't have the image of the concept "resonance" )\ $?$.